# Add unlimited Text input DatePickers to fields added after the DOM is loaded using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have a Project app that loads any number of "Task" records into a page.  It builds the Task record HTML with JavaScript and then adds the Tasks to the DOM after the page is loaded.

I need to attach a Date Picker library to some Date fields for each task record.

I can use pretty much any library but I was trying to use this light weight one here https://github.com/camerond/jquery-minical

After you load that library you can generally do something like this to turn a text input into a date picker fields...  Working demo here http://codepen.io/jasondavis/pen/LEaVbE?editors=101

```
<input name="date_input" type="text">

// Code that is supposed to make a text filed into a Date-time selector/picker!
$(".date_input").minical({
    trigger: "a.calendar_icon"
});
```

Now my demo app is loacted here for this question... http://jsfiddle.net/jasondavis/pk109mkm/

This function below is called for each Task record and it creates a Task entry into the DOM...

```
// Add new Task Row HTML to the DOM
function add_task_row(taskRow){

    // Merge Function Parameters with Default Values
    taskRow = merge({
        taskid: '',
        projectid: '',
        name: '',
        description: '',
        status: '',
        priority: '',
        type: '',
        sort: '',
        heading: '',
        date_started: '',
        date_completed: '',
        date_due: '',
        milestone_id: '',
        assigned_user_id: '',
        targetElement: 'project_tasks',
    }, taskRow || {});  

    // var num is used to have a Number assigned to each Task Row.
    // 1st We get the value stored in #tasks_count
    var num = document.getElementById('tasks_count').value;

    // Create a DIV Node for our new Task Row and set the ID attribute value to 'task_'+num
    var newTaskRow = document.createElement('div');
    newTaskRow.setAttribute('id','task_'+num);  

    newTaskRow.innerHTML =  '<span class="handle" title="Drag and Drop to Reorder Tasks"></span>';


    // Add a Project Task Row
    newTaskRow.innerHTML +=  '<div class="task-name-wrap"><input class="name" name="name_'+num+'" id="name_'+num+'" placeholder="Name:" size=45 type="text" value="'+taskRow.name+'"></div>';
    newTaskRow.innerHTML += '<div class="task-status-wrap"><span class="selection-field-label">Status:</span><select name="status_'+num+'" id="status_'+num+'" class="status">'+buildFormSelection(statusArray, taskRow.status)+'</select></div>';
    newTaskRow.innerHTML += '<div class="task-priority-wrap"><span class="selection-field-label">Priority:</span><select name="priority_'+num+'" id="priority_'+num+'" class="priority">'+buildFormSelection(prioritiesArray, taskRow.priority)+'</select></div>';
    newTaskRow.innerHTML += '<div class="task-type-wrap"><span class="selection-field-label">Type:</span><select name="type_'+num+'" id="type_'+num+'" class="type">'+buildFormSelection(typesArray, taskRow.type)+'</select></div>';

    // milestone
    newTaskRow.innerHTML += '<div class="task-milestone-wrap"><span class="selection-field-label">Milestone:</span><select name="milestone_id_'+num+'" id="milestone_'+num+'" class="milestone">'+buildFormSelectionMultidimensionalArray(milestonesArray, taskRow.milestone_id)+'</select></div>';

    newTaskRow.innerHTML +=  '<input name="date_due_'+num+'" id="date_due_'+num+'" class="date_due" size=15 type="text" value="'+taskRow.date_due+'">';

    newTaskRow.innerHTML +=  '<input name="assigned_user_id_'+num+'" id="assigned_user_id_'+num+'" class="assigned_user_id" size=15 type="text" value="">';

    newTaskRow.innerHTML +=  '<input class="date_input" autocomplete="off" type="text" name="date_completed" id="date_completed" value="" title="" tabindex="0" size="11" maxlength="10"><a class="calendar_icon" href="#"></a>';


    newTaskRow.innerHTML += '<div class="task-tools-wrap"><a class="insert_task" data-parent-task-id="task_'+num+'"><span class="insert-arrow-icon"></span></a><a class="delete_task" onclick="remove_item_row('+num+')"><span class="trash-icon"></span> Delete</a></div>';

    newTaskRow.innerHTML += '<hr><br style="clear:both;">';

    var task = document.getElementById('project_tasks');
    task.appendChild(newTaskRow);

}
```

---

**So after my Task records are added to the page, I need to somehow attach a working Date picker to each `.date_input` input field!
Any help or ideas how to do this?**

To recap, I need to be able to dynamically add any number of Text input fields to a webpage after the page has loaded and then have those input fields work with a JavaScript Date Time picker/selector.

It can be any library pretty much for the date picker.  I am not sure how I can get this to work with:
**a) Unlimited input fields.

b) An input field that is added after the DOM has already loaded!**

Please help!

---

**UPDATED PROBLEM**

On Line 486 of this JSFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/pk109mkm/7/ is this code setting up the DatePicker library for each Task record.  It works as far as making a usable Date Picker for the fileds we assign it to.   However for some unknown reason, it does not honor any special options that I try to pass into it!

```
$(task).find(".date_input").minical({
    trigger: "a.calendar_icon"
});
```

To demonstrate, here is a new JSFiddle with the exact same code except I have passed in an Options Object to the DatePicker object.... http://jsfiddle.net/jasondavis/pk109mkm/10/

The options object looks like this...

```
$(task).find(".date_input").minical({
  offset: {
    x: 100,
    y: 50
  },
  trigger: "a.calendar_icon",
  read_only: true,
  align_to_trigger: false,
  date_format: function(date) {
    return [date.getDate(), date.getMonth() + 1, date.getFullYear()].join("/");
  },
  appendCalendarTo: function() {
      return $('#project_tasks');
  },
  //initialize_with_date: true,
  show_clear_link: true,
});
```

If you see the example JSFiddle you will notice that none of these Options are being used!  If you view the Browser console you will also see that there is no errors!

Now if you go to this demo JSFiddle example http://jsfiddle.net/jasondavis/2q2d6gza/ which does not add multiple Date Pickers after the DOM is loaded....you will see the exact same code and options make a big difference as they actually take affect in this demo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding

```
$(task).find(".date_input").minical({
    trigger: "a.calendar_icon"
});
```

to the end of your function.

Like

```
// Add new Task Row HTML to the DOM
function add_task_row(taskRow){

    // Merge Function Parameters with Default Values
    taskRow = merge({
        taskid: '',
        projectid: '',
        name: '',
        description: '',
        status: '',
        priority: '',
        type: '',
        sort: '',
        heading: '',
        date_started: '',
        date_completed: '',
        date_due: '',
        milestone_id: '',
        assigned_user_id: '',
        targetElement: 'project_tasks',
    }, taskRow || {});  

    // var num is used to have a Number assigned to each Task Row.
    // 1st We get the value stored in #tasks_count
    var num = document.getElementById('tasks_count').value;

    // Create a DIV Node for our new Task Row and set the ID attribute value to 'task_'+num
    var newTaskRow = document.createElement('div');
    newTaskRow.setAttribute('id','task_'+num);  

    newTaskRow.innerHTML =  '<span class="handle" title="Drag and Drop to Reorder Tasks"></span>';


    // Add a Project Task Row
    newTaskRow.innerHTML +=  '<div class="task-name-wrap"><input class="name" name="name_'+num+'" id="name_'+num+'" placeholder="Name:" size=45 type="text" value="'+taskRow.name+'"></div>';
    newTaskRow.innerHTML += '<div class="task-status-wrap"><span class="selection-field-label">Status:</span><select name="status_'+num+'" id="status_'+num+'" class="status">'+buildFormSelection(statusArray, taskRow.status)+'</select></div>';
    newTaskRow.innerHTML += '<div class="task-priority-wrap"><span class="selection-field-label">Priority:</span><select name="priority_'+num+'" id="priority_'+num+'" class="priority">'+buildFormSelection(prioritiesArray, taskRow.priority)+'</select></div>';
    newTaskRow.innerHTML += '<div class="task-type-wrap"><span class="selection-field-label">Type:</span><select name="type_'+num+'" id="type_'+num+'" class="type">'+buildFormSelection(typesArray, taskRow.type)+'</select></div>';

    // milestone
    newTaskRow.innerHTML += '<div class="task-milestone-wrap"><span class="selection-field-label">Milestone:</span><select name="milestone_id_'+num+'" id="milestone_'+num+'" class="milestone">'+buildFormSelectionMultidimensionalArray(milestonesArray, taskRow.milestone_id)+'</select></div>';

    newTaskRow.innerHTML +=  '<input name="date_due_'+num+'" id="date_due_'+num+'" class="date_due" size=15 type="text" value="'+taskRow.date_due+'">';

    newTaskRow.innerHTML +=  '<input name="assigned_user_id_'+num+'" id="assigned_user_id_'+num+'" class="assigned_user_id" size=15 type="text" value="">';

    newTaskRow.innerHTML +=  '<input class="date_input" autocomplete="off" type="text" name="date_completed" id="date_completed" value="" title="" tabindex="0" size="11" maxlength="10"><a class="calendar_icon" href="#"></a>';


    newTaskRow.innerHTML += '<div class="task-tools-wrap"><a class="insert_task" data-parent-task-id="task_'+num+'"><span class="insert-arrow-icon"></span></a><a class="delete_task" onclick="remove_item_row('+num+')"><span class="trash-icon"></span> Delete</a></div>';

    newTaskRow.innerHTML += '<hr><br style="clear:both;">';

    var task = document.getElementById('project_tasks');
    task.appendChild(newTaskRow);

    $(newTaskRow).find(".date_input").minical({
        trigger: "a.calendar_icon"
    });

}
```

Here is the working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/pk109mkm/7/

Comment: This is not as efficient as it could be. By doing `$(task).find()`, you are searching through all the tasks in the list, not just the new one you just added. You should do capture the return value from `task.appendChild()` and search only within that.

Comment: Yeah fixed that up. I would have done all the DOM work in jQuery to make it tidier myself.

Comment: Thanks for the help and i'm always open to improvements.  Always love learning better JavaScript techniques as it;s my least known language but I think it is one of the funnest!  I am building upon and existing app in this case so I was trying to stick with some of the existing code where I can.

Comment: @DGS I will select your answer as the answer to this question in the morning.  I have amended my question with an updated issue that I wanted to ask you if you might have an idea for since you are familiar now with this question.  If not I will write out a new question.  Basically in your example, I cannot use any Options passed into the library as they are ignored.  WHen I make a new JSFiddle which does not add the fields into the DOM after page load, then my custom options work.  I just wanted to see if you might know if there is an easy solution to this issue?  Thanks ...see my question